# Save only selected image to svg file

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg

I have 4 artboards as shown below
[image]

I would like to save just first image in separate SVG file. I do select image and save as SVG. I got images from first and second artborads overlaped. First image is trace of second, pixel one.

[image]

Why AI saves first and second artboards? Why they are overlaped? How to save just selected image?

And why I can't post SVG images in this article?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **[slice tool](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/slices-image-maps.html#create_slices)** to overcome the lack of option to save each art board as a separate file.

Using this tool will will enable to *Save for Web and devices* where you will be able to select the setting of the svg export and after that in the save menu decide if you want to export:

- all slices (even those created automatically by the software),
- slices you have created manually
- or just a single slice that you have selected either on the artboard or in the *Save for Web and devices* settings window.

Answer (score 1):

The SVG format is actually readable in code form, so a neat trick you could use is:

- copy your object in Illustrator (Ctrl + C)
- open any text editor (e.g. notepad)
- paste (Ctrl + V)
- save the result (you should see the SVG code) as a .txt file.
- rename the file into a .svg format. This file can now be opened in Illustrator (or other vector software).